# npm version in vscode is different to installed version

Tags: npm, version

If I type `node -v` in VSCode's integrated terminal the version number is returned immediately, (10.15.0), but `npm -v` takes about 6 seconds to return a value (6.7.0).

Is this normal?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's normal. npm requires a bit of overhead to bootstrap.

If you're using a version manager like nvm, try uninstalling your system node - additionally, if you installed your system node with homebrew, try removing that and installing it the official way (directly from the website, or via something like nvm which downloads it from there). I've seen many reports that brew-installed node/npm is slow.